# Why is the original poster not involved in approval of edits?

Tags: discussion

If I answer or post a question, and that post is edited by someone, I am not involved in the approval process of those edits. Why?

If text is edited anywhere on the site it goes into a queue of edits for users who have earned the "Editor" badge. These editors then decide whether an edit is approved or denied. What about the original author? Shouldn't that person have a say? I find this to be a very strange way of "fixing" text.

Is it less confrontational this way?

Is it the experience that original posters will always deny any edits to their own work?

Most edits seem to be from people trying to slightly bump up their status. Is this really needed?

Could edits be discussed in a different thread from the main Q&A?

Maybe having the OP approve edits would keep the number of edits in the general queue down a bit.

Comment: the OP can be involved. your SE inbox is pinged when an edit has been suggested and if check it out you can approve or reject the edit without needing any further votes. otherwise you can ignore it and let the community decide which requires 2-3 votes

Comment: What are you talking about? If anything the OP is *more* involved. They have a binding vote for an edit, meaning they can single-handedly reject or approve an edit on their post... they also get notifications when a post of theirs is edited...

Comment: I had an answer edited. It was rejected. Then approved. Then rejected. Then approved. All before I ever saw it (it was the middle of the night and a very old answer). Since someone else already approved the edit, it went through and I was not involved. And I did not see a place to roll it back - sorry, I might have just missed it in the UI.

Comment: Why you are as OP is not involved in approval of edits? It would be so much faster and less controversial if you actually did get involved... Since as OP you have binding vote your approval avoids spending effort of 3-5 people to look at the change. Please definitely get involved. (I'm somewhat puzzled by question - so maybe misunderstood what you are asking and hence comment and not an answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If every suggested edit *hinged* on the post owner's approval or rejection, then a large number of valid edits would be incorrectly approved or rejected because the post owner simply doesn't know any better. This is where reviewers come in: they are expected to understand the edit system better and so have a better say in whether an edit should be approved or rejected.

To compensate for this the post owner is given a binding approve/reject vote on edits that they *do* get a chance to review before the decision is committed. The only caveat is that you kinda have to be there when the edit is first submitted for review. Which is another problem that would be created by requiring owner decision to commit an edit: if the owner is inactive or otherwise doesn't review, the edit will remain pending indefinitely, until they show up again, if they ever do.

(Of course, this all doesn't take into account the fact that many reviewers are just as unreliable at reviewing as new users and have no business participating in review in the first place, but that's just not how the system was designed.)

Comment: I kind of addressed this in the comment to the question - but I see what you are saying. I was not around, so the edits were approved. They were bad edits and I did not see why they were approved at all. Or why there was an edit in the first place. :)

Comment: @sbzoom: That's where your ability to roll back edits to your own posts comes in handy.

Comment: Ok. Did some more clicking around and found the "rollback" link. It all makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

There are some things you would need to know about edits:

- Users with over 2K reputation [skip the queue entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit); their reputation level is trusted enough to make minor-seeming edits with little oversight.
- The OP gets a notification whenever a post is edited.  You would have received a notification when I edited your post.
- You have the ability to be involved in your edit; if you feel like the edit was wrong or in error, or didn't truly improve your post, then you can always roll it back.  I've done this on occasion since there [are occasions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/326251/revisions) when my verbiage is ***just fine***, thanks.

Above all your idea that the OP should be more directly involved to *prevent* posts from making it into the queue is counterproductive.  There are a ***lot*** of accounts which only post one thing and never return, and someone comes along and edits it.  If the OP isn't guaranteed to return, why should we involve them in the process?  It would slow down our ability to make concise, reasonable edits (for example, capitalizing the letter "i" when it needs to be, otherwise every post that doesn't do this is truly an abomination).

Comment: Same thing. I have had posts edited that fixed code indenting, brackets, back-ticks. No problem. But when someone edits my grammar - and gets it wrong - well that's just weird. I was looking for a way to make a comment about the edit like, "Hey, I want the grammar to stay that way, thanks." So instead I made edited the post back to its original state.

Comment: Note: for truly minor 2k edits, there is no notification. It's fairly difficult to trigger this in practice, though.

Comment: @sbzoom:  No real reason to leave a comment in that context in my mind; a simple rollback of the edit would've sent the message.